# In quantum double slit experiment what is the state vector or density matrix of the electron after the electron passes through the two slits?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, double-slit-experiment, density-operator

Also I would like to confirm my thinking on quantum double slit experiment.

Before  it passes through the two slits (slit 1 and slit 2), is the electron state vector $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\left(\left|slit1\right> + \left|slit2\right>\right)$? Because it is a pure state it is a coherent state. Therefore it exhibits interference pattern.

What is the state after? If the electron state interference with itself:

Does it mean state after is the same?

Comment: I see some confusion regarding coherent and pure states. Not every pure state is coherent. Also, the final state of the electron is only known after it hits the measuring screen. Your final state doesn't really make any sense.

Comment: @QuantumBrick I do not perform any measurement here, before the slit or after the slit. Since the electron interferes with itself, I think that may be the one.

Comment: @QuantumBrick Thank you for pointing out that not every pure state is coherent. But is the electron state a coherent state before passing through the slit? I read that it is.

Comment: @QuantumBrick I have corrected the state after. I think it is the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let's imagine the double slit experiment you proposed as something simpler, yet equivalent. In the electron beam experiment you have a free particle's wavefunction that suddenly faces a decision: go left or right, and then collapses at a screen, giving you a result. I propose finding an analogous example with spin: suppose we have a hydrogen atom trapped inside a cavity where a strong magnetic field resides. The electron surely has a spin, which can be measured, and points along the field. It must be up or down: it's the same as the particle travelling through slits, but this time the degree of freedom is discrete and makes mathematical treatment and intuition a little bit easier. Right or left is exchanged by up or down.

Well, this means our state vector is a superposition of up and down. It only chooses a definite direction when we measure. This means that in your double slit experiment the same applies: the state vector is the same all the way until the electron hits the screen, where it shows an interference pattern (if you didn't measure which slit if passed through) or if it went right or left (if you did measure after).

Answer (score 0):

You can model the wave function as collapsing into either $|slit1\rangle$ or $slit2\rangle$ when the electron passes through the slits, or when the electron hits the detector, or when a human experimenter comes along and examines the results.  The corresponding theories make all the same predictions (this is a theorem of von Neumann), so it's entirely up to you which one you prefer to use.